# FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ac', but it was: A custom an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

A very similar example can be found here:
[firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

```
useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(collection(db, "posts"), (snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot);
      //setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    })
  }, [])
```

[error on the localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nzsu.png)

Comment: Yeah, here is the document to handle these type of issues. `https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference`

Comment: @NadeemTaj can you please elaborate more on how to fix this error? I am new to react and don't know much. Thanks